# Будут ли создаваться новые объекты?

Tags: java, массивы

Мне нужно заполнять массив объектами по-умолчанию. Эту операцию придётся выполнять очень часто. Для этого использую такой код:

```
Point[][] myArray = new Point[9][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            myArray[i][j] = new Point(-1; -1);
        }
    }
```

Я хочу узнать, будут ли при этом создаваться новые временные объекты, которые потом сборщику мусора придётся убирать, убирать и прерывать плавное выполнение программы? Может быть есть более простой и удобный способ сделать то же самое?

Comment: Сделать что то же самое?

Comment: @DmitriyD, Да. Мне нужно заполнить массив. Нужен способ который будет делать это быстро и не создавать временных объектов, которые будут загружать сборщик мусора. Мой способ нормальный? Или нужно это сделать по-другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новый объекты будут создаваться, когда вызывается new.
Если я правильно понял вопрос (несколько раз вызывать данные циклы на одном и том же массиве), то да, сборщик будет вызываться.
Не знаю, что за задача стоит, но если так не хочется создавать новые, то чем не вариант сделать метод, который будет нужные элементы массива устанавливать в значение по умолчанию?
Т.е вместо:
`myArray[i][j] = new Point(-1; -1);`
Что-то вроде:
`Point.setDeafualt(myArray[i][j])`
Который координаты точки будет устанавливать в (-1, -1).
З.Ы. Есть метод `Arrays.fill()`, который заполнит массив нужными значениями.
**UPD**
Метод выгдядит примерно так:

```java
setDeafualt(Point p) {
    p.setX(-1);
    p.setY(-1);
}
```

Т.е. один раз где-то инициализировать, а потом уже проходить этим методом.

Comment: можно написать, конечно, метод. Но ведь он точно так же будет создавать новые объекты. Ведь в нём я тоже буду использовать new. А fill, насколько я знаю, заполняет массив ссылками на один и тот же объект. И я не смогу поменять значение какого-либо элемента не изменив другие.

Comment: @gibsonff, так вы просите создавать разные объекты, но при этом, чтобы они не создавались. Это противоречащие друг другу задачи. Единственное что могу порекомендовать, это создавать их в стеке с помощью специальных библиотек или хранить в массиве не экземпляры класса Point, а лишь координаты. А в методы класса Point передавать значения из этого массива.

Comment: @gibsonff в написанном методе не создавать элемент, а устанавливать его поля в нужное значение. Сейчас отредактирую ответ, чтобы на примере показать.
Про `fill()` да, ошибся.

Answer (score 1):

Если объект `Point` константный, т.е. все его поля объявлены как `final`, то можно сделать так

```java
class Point {
  public static final Point Default = new Point(-1, -1);
  ..........
}

 myArray[i][j] = Point.Default;
```

Тогда у вас будет объект в одном единственном экземпляре

Comment: нет, этот вариант не подойдёт. Мне нужно заполнять массив значениями по-умолчанию, но тут же я буду изменять отдельные выбранные элементы в зависимости от логики программы. И это должно выполняться в цикле (очень часто), и объекты создаваться не должны, чтобы сборщик мусора не тормозил выполнение.

Comment: @gibsonff Вот и заполните одним дефолтным объектом, а потом создайте новый объект с нужными параметрами